# bash PS1 shows /home/boom/git instead of ~/git

Tags: bash, path, home-directory

When I start bash, it looks like `boom@server:~$`, but when I start changing current directory, it shows full path. Even if I switch dir back to home, it shows `boom@server:/home/boom$`. how can I fix that?

using Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS amd64

Comment: What does `echo $HOME` and `echo $PS1` print?

Comment: @TheSlater $HOME is `/home/boom/`, $PS1 is `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$`

Comment: Same here, but i have no backslash after /home/boom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash at the end of your `$HOME` variable is the problem. Try first

```
HOME=/home/boom
```

and everything is normal. Search in `~/.profile` and/or `~/.bashrc` files where your `$HOME` variable is set.

Comment: Shouldn't  `HOME` be set (and exported) at login? There should be no need to set it in the dot-files.

Comment: The problem must come from somewhere.